# Find the equation of the tangent line to the graph of $g(u(x),v(x))$ at $x=1$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find the equation of the tangent line to the graph of $g(u(x),v(x))$ at $x=1$ if $(u'(1),v'(1))=(3,1)$ and the equation to the tangent plane to the graph of $g(u,v)$ at $(1,2)$ is $4-z-2u+5v=0$.

Doubts:

1. I don't get this question, I'm being asked to find a tangent line to a function of two variables, so I should get infinitely many lines (all the ones forming the tangent plane?).
2. Does $g(u,v)$ and $g(u(x),v(x))$ mean the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

The statement is not very precise, so let me rephrase what (I guess) is meant.

Let $z=g(u,v)$ a function of two variables. Consider the function $f(x)=g(u(x),v(x))$, where $u,v$ are real functions of one variable. Find the equation of the tangent line to the graph of $f$ at $x=1$.

We know that the tangent line is:
$$y-f(1)=f'(1)\, (x-1)$$
and by the chain rule, we have:
$$f'(x)=\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial u}(u(x),v(x))\, u'(x)+\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial v}(u(x),v(x))\, v'(x)$$

On the other hand, we also know that the tangent plane to $g$ at $(1,2)$ is:
$$z-g(1,2)=\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial u}(1,2)\, (u-1)+\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial v}(1,2)\, (v-2)$$
Comparing this formula with the given plane, we obtain:
$$g(1,2)=12 \qquad \dfrac{\partial g}{\partial u}(1,2)=-2 \qquad \dfrac{\partial g}{\partial v}(1,2)=5$$

PROBLEM: I do not know if there is something missing in the question, but you only have data to solve it if $u(1)=1$, $v(1)=2$. Assuming this, we continue.

Substituting in the derivative at the right values:
$$f'(1)=-2 \cdot 3+5 \cdot 1=-1$$
and also 
$$f(1)=g(u(1),v(1))=g(1,2)=12$$

Finally, the equation is:
$$y-12=-(x-1)$$

Comment: I don't understand how $f(x)=g(u(x),v(x))$ and $g(u,v)$ are different, it's like we're making $u$ and $v$ depend on $x$ on the first one but not in $g$? Could you give me a example of how $f$ vs $g$ would look?

Comment: Also, could you give some more details on the part after you say "we know the tangent line is..."? I'm sorry, but I'm having a lot of troubles understanding this.

Comment: An example: $g(u,v)=u+v$ is a function of two variables; $u(x)=x$, $v(x)=x^2$ are functions of one variable; $f(x)=x + x^2$ is a function of only one variable, but it could be expressed as $f(x)=g(u(x),v(x))$.

Comment: And what would $f(x)=g(u(x),v(x))$ look like?

Comment: You need to know the theory, at least: the equation of the tangent line, the equation of the tangent plane, and the chain rule in several variables. I guess the latter is the most involved.

Comment: It's mostly when you say "comparing these...", I don't understand how you got those numbers, thanks for the patience.

Comment: I think that the most useful intuition is thinking about an object moving on a plane. At each instant $t$, the object is at a point $(x,y)$. Now, consider a magnitude, for instance the temperature $T$, that depends on the position $(x,y)$ through a function of two variables $T=g(x,y)$. But you would like to know how the temperature changes along time, so you could think of $T=g(x(t),y(t))$, which is a function of a single variable.

Comment: Well, "comparing this..." is the easy part :) Just do the arithmetic: those are the only numbers so that you obtain the given equation of the plane.

Comment: Oh, I think I've understood it now.

 So when someone says $h=g(x,y)$ and then $f=g(x(t),y(t))$, I can think of $f$ as the composition of $g$ with a parametrization of it's variables?

Comment: Also, rereading your answer, shouldn't the tangent plane equation be $z-g(1,2)=g_u(1,2)\cdot (u-1)+g_v(1,2) \cdot (v-2)$ (u and v instead of x and y multiplying the partials)?